# Is there a way to package a MS Word macro together with the associated toolbar icon

Tags: ms-word, toolbar

I have developed two MS Word macros and assigned each an icon. I have also added a custom toolbar, named after the project, and added the two macro icons to that toolbar. Now, how do I package the whole thing (macros, icons, and custom toolbar) to send it to my customer?

Comment: What version of word are you using?

Comment: I need this to work on Word 2003, but if there is a way to get it work on a latter version that would still be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to move the toolbar definition and the macros to a template, then save the template (a DOT file) to the word autoload templates location on the users machine (the template will contain the icon images, and macro code, so the DOT file is all you should have to distribute).

For details on where see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/load-or-unload-a-template-or-add-in-program-HA010105537.aspx